# Almacenar datos en Cookies CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

estoy trabajando con las Cookies en CodeIgniter pero tengo dudas sobre lo que le tengo que enviar la Cookie. Este es mi ejemplo de Cookie, no me marca error pero no se como es que almacenan la información del usuario.

```
function set_cookie() {
  $this->load->helper('cookie');

  $cookie= array(
    'name'   => 'NombreCookie',
    'value'  => 'Demostracion de Cookie en CI',
    'expire' => '3600',
    'secure' => TRUE
  );

  $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

Después traigo lo que almaceno la Cookie con la siguiente función

```
function get_cookie() {
  $data['cookie'] = $this->input->cookie('NombreCookie', true);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Finalmente **hago un alert con JavaScript** y me trae lo que guarde en value de la Cookie pensando que me iba a traer más información como por ejemplo de donde se conectó...

Espero que me puedan apoyar sobre los datos que le tengo que decir que almacene.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las cookies son similares a las sesiones solo que las sesiones se almacenan en el servidor, pero para que PHP reconozca que sesión es de que cliente, se almacena una cookie en el cliente llamada PHPSESSID, esta tiene el número de sesión y enlaza al cliente con el servidor.

Las sessiones permite almacenar información que puede ser de utilidad durante la navegación de un usuario por el sitio web. Mientras dure la sesión, la información estará disponible para el código PHP cada vez que el usuario solicite una página.

Algunos ejemplos de información que puede resultar interesante guardar en sesión:

- Si el usuario se ha autenticado o no.
- Identificador del usuario que se ha autenticado.
- Productos añadidos a un carro de la compra.
- Datos de facturación y de dirección para hacer un pedido.

Las cookies también permite almacenar información durante la navegación del usuario, pero con el fin de usarla en futuras conexiones (futuras sesiones), más que en la misma sesión.

Ejemplos de información que podría ser interesante guardarla en la cookie:

- Si el usuario ha marcado el check para recordar usuario y contraseña.
- El usuario y la contraseña introducidas por el usuario, para que cuando vuelva a nuestro sitio web, se autentique automáticamente sin solicitar otra vez usuario y contraseña.
- El idioma seleccionado por el usuario la ultima vez que accedió, para mostrarle directamente la página en ese idioma y no solicitarle que elija el idioma cada vez que entre.
- El último producto que compró (si el sitio web es una tienda online) para mostrarle ofertas de productos relacionados.

Ahora si quieres saber de donde se esta conectando un cliente como leí que estabas buscando almacenar u cualquier otra información con respecto a la conexión del cliente puedes usar la variable **$_SERVER**, por ejemplo puede obtener la ip del cliente así:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
```

Una vez obtenida la puedes almacenar en una cookie, ejemplo con tu código:

```
function set_cookie() {
  $this->load->helper('cookie');

  $cookie= array(
    'name'   => 'ipCliente',
    'value'  => $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'],
    'expire' => '3600',
    'secure' => TRUE
  );

  $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

Espero te sirva esta información.

Comment: codeigniter provee un método [`$this->input->ip_address();`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address) que toma en cuenta proxies y otras yerbas